# How can i copy community image on azure using python api or CLI of azure

Tags: python, linux, azure, copy, vhd

I did not find any documentation for how to copy vhd on azure using python api, can anyone help me... also i have tried to create instance from image on the vmdepot community but when i run the following command i got this error:

```
$ azure vm create instanceahmed -o vmdepot-14776-1-1 -l "West US" ahmed P@ssw0rd --ssh 22 --verbose
......
verbose: Creating VM
verbose: Deleting image
info:    VM image deleted: vmdepot-14776-1-1-c5febcb3
verbose: Uri : http://portalvhdsf4048vkh9c007.blob.core.windows.net/vm-images/community- 23970-525c8c75-8901-4870-a937-7277414a6eaa-1.vhd
info:    Blob deleted: http://portalvhdsf4048vkh9c007.blob.core.windows.net/vm- images/community-23970-525c8c75-8901-4870-a937-7277414a6eaa-1.vhd
info:    vm create command OK
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do what "-o" do with Azure with these steps:

1. Get the URL of your image on the community:

   ```
   http://vmdepoteastus.blob.core.windows.net/linux-community-store/community-23970-525c8c75-8901-4870-a937-7277414a6eaa-1.vhd
   ```
2. Create a new affinity group if you have one skip this point:

   ```
   $ azure account affinity-group create mystoragegroup --location "West US"
   ```
3. Create a new storage account if you have an account skip this point:

   ```
   $ azure storage account create mystorageazure --affinity-group mystoragegroup
   ```
4. Get the Primary secret key of new storage account using this command:

   ```
   $ azure account storage keys list mystorageazure
   output:
   data:    Primary:  Your SECRET STORAGE KEY
   ```
5. Create new account storage inside this storage account:

   ```
   $ azure storage container create  --permission Blob  -a mystorageazure  -k  Your SECRET STORAGE KEY  mycontainerazure
   ```
6. Upload your image to the your account storage container:

   ```
   $ azure vm disk upload --verbose http://vmdepoteastus.blob.core.windows.net/linux-community-store/community-23970-525c8c75-8901-4870-a937-7277414a6eaa-1.vhd http://mystorageazure.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainerazure/elastichpcvm.vhd  Your SECRET STORAGE KEY
   ```
7. Create your local image:

   ```
   $ azure vm image create mystorageimage --location "West US" --blob-url http://mystorageazure.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainerazure/elastichpcvm.vhd --os linux
   ```
8. Create your virtual machine using your local image:

   ```
   $ azure vm create mystoragemachine  mystorageimage ahmed P@ssw0rd --location "West US" --ssh 22
   ```

Comment: This is totally unrelated to the original question, but you helped me 2.5 years later with the last 3 steps with another problem! :)

Answer (score -1):

This seems to me like the cli issue. Can you please tell us

- what version of the azure cli are you using. To get the version execute: azure -v
- Can you provide us the version of publishsettings.xml file you are currently using? You can get the publishsettings xml file by executing:  azure account download

Comment: my azure version is 0.7.2 my publishsettings version 2.0